# What does a Coroutine Join do?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

So for example I have the following code:

```
scope.launch {
    val job = launch {
        doSomethingHere()
    }
    job.join()

    callOnlyWhenJobAboveIsDone()
}
```

`Job.join()` is state as such in the documentation:

> Suspends coroutine until this job is complete. This invocation resumes normally (without exception) when the job is complete for any reason and the Job of the invoking coroutine is still active. This function also starts the corresponding coroutine if the Job was still in new state.

If I understand it correctly, since `join()` suspends the coroutine until its completed, then my code above will do exactly what it wants. That is, the method `callOnlyWhenJobAboveIsDone()` will only be called when `doSomethingHere()` is finished. Is that correct?

Can anyone explain further the use case for `job.join()`? Thanks in advance.

Explaining further my usecase:

```
val storeJobs = ArrayList<Job>()

fun callThisFunctionMultipleTimes() {
    scope.launch {
        val job = launch {
            doSomethingHere()
        }
        storeJobs.add(job) 
        job.join()

        callOnlyWhenJobAboveIsDone()
    }
}

fun callOnlyWhenJobAboveIsDone() {
    // Check if there is still an active job 
    // by iterating through the storedJobs
    // and checking if any is active
    // if no job is active do some other things
}
```

is this a valid usecase for `job.join()`?

Comment: why don't you just run the code to find out

Comment: @TimCastelijns I did. I just want confirmation. You see sometimes, it works the way we think it works but in reality its not how we though it is. That is the reason why I am asking.

Comment: *sometimes, it works the way we think it works but in reality its not how we though it is.* - that is why you run the code, to see what happens in reality. Since you already did that and surely observed the result of the code, I'm not sure what's left of your question

Comment: @TimCastelijns I believe you're being a bit harsh here. Anything involving concurrency/synchronization is not as easy as "run the code and see for yourself", especially if the OP is not comfortable with coroutines and how they relate to threads. It could be by chance that the OP came across the result he got, or it could be environment dependant. He's merely asking whether his conclusion can be generalized or not, which is fair IMO.

Comment: @Joffrey alright, I understand. To me it seemed more like he was asking for confirmation if the documentation was correct, which in this case *can* be answered by running the code

Comment: Thank you so much for your understanding. I'm new to `Coroutines` and I'm trying to grasp as much as I could. I got no one else to ask but this site so I really appreciate all answers here. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> That is, the method callOnlyWhenJobAboveIsDone() will only be called when doSomethingHere() is finished. Is that correct?

Yes.

> Can anyone explain further the use case for job.join()?

In your case there is actually no need for another job, you could just write:

```
scope.launch {
    doSomethingHere()
    callOnlyWhenJobAboveIsDone()
}
```

That will do the exact same thing, so it is not really a usecase for a Job. Now there are other cases when `.join()` is really useful.

1. You want to run (launch) multiple asynchronous actions in parallel, and wait for all of them to finish:

```
      someData
       .map { Some.asyncAction(it) } // start in parallel
       .forEach { it.join() } // wait for all of them
```

2. You have to keep track of an asynchronous state, for example an update:

```
     var update = Job()

     fun doUpdate() {
        update.cancel() // don't update twice at the same time
        update = launch {
          someAsyncCode()
        }
     }
```

Now to make sure that the last update was done, for example if you want to use some updated data, you can just:

```
 update.join()
```

anywhere, you can also

```
 update.cancel()
```

if you want to.

Whats really useful about `launch {}` is that it not only returns a Job, but also attaches the Job to the CoroutineScope. Through that you can keep track of every async action happening inside your application. For example in your UI you could make every Element extend the CoroutineScope, then you can just cancel the scope if the Element leaves the rendered area, and all updates / animations in it will get stopped.

Comment: *there is no need for another job, you could just write* - suggesting to use code Y instead of X does not answer the question whether or not code X results in Z

Comment: @tim the question was about usecases of `Job`, how should I answer that without telling the OP that his code is *not a usecase* ?

Comment: there are 2 questions actually, you might have overlooked the first

Comment: @tim added a *yes* just for you :)

Comment: @JonasWilms Thank you so much. I added my specific usecase in my question. Is that a valid use case or Is there a better way to do it? If it is a valid usecase, I'm just not confident enough coz, Instead of 1 coroutine, I am creating two and this method will double the coroutine count.

Comment: @archie I'm not sure what that code is supposed to do, but keeping an array of jobs is usually the wrong way.

Comment: @JonasWilms really why is that?

Comment: @archie in your case you could just `scope.launch { }` and then check `scope.isActive` [doc](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/)

Comment: @JonasWilms when would I check `scope.isActive`? If I check it inside the launch, it would return true.

Answer (score 9):

Kotlin's `Job.join()` is the non-blocking equivalent of Java's `Thread.join()`.

So your assumption is correct: the point of `job.join()` is to wait for the completion of the receiver `job` before executing the rest of the current coroutine.

However, instead of blocking the thread that calls `join()` (like Java's `Thread.join()` would do) it simply suspends the coroutine calling `join()`, leaving the current thread free to do whatever it pleases (like executing another coroutine) in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

```
val queryProduct = GlobalScope.async {                        
    }

val verification = GlobalScope.async {  
    }
            
GlobalScope.launch {
    verification.join()
    queryProduct.join()                  
    }
```

This is how I use join(). When two asyncs are completed, another launch starts.

Comment: Use caution when using `GlobalScope` with coroutines as discussed here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/#:~:text=this%20is%20a%20delicate%20api.

Comment: why not use await as intended?